# how to do interactive debug on nodeclipse

Tags: eclipse, windows, node.js, eclipse-plugin, nodeclipse

I am running Eclipse Kepler 2 on Windows 7 with latest nodeclipse installed and nodejs

When I debug, I don't understand why i cannot enter into the console box to see the values of variable (like in pydev). This [document](https://nodeclipse.uservoice.com/forums/216804-general/suggestions/4305017-console-access-to-the-node-especially-in-debug-mo) tells me to use "Expression View". But **is there a way to enter into interactive console of eclipse to get output with nodeclipse plugin?**

Here is what is installed in my eclipse.
[image]

Also, I see that there is a separate interactive console (see image), but i can't seem to enter anything over there. Am i missing some plugins? I tried installing eclipse plugin - chromedevtools and nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nodeclipse is already shipped with chromedevtools (0.3.9 versus Google chromedevtools that were 0.3.8)

> is there a way to enter into interactive console of eclipse to get output with nodeclipse plugin?

It should be tested and/or developed at https://github.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/

BTW: Hint Right-click on Perspective tabs panel and select Hide text. The toolbar panel will be more compact.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I looked at the link you sent. So i see that interactive console hasn't been developed yet - "Integrate console window (library unknown) -> currently can use StartExplorer (bundled with Enide)"